# reflection principle brownian motion

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

In this [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle_(Wiener_process)) they use the strong markov property but i don't understand why we need it. Could anyone explain it to me? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the strong Markov property to remove the condition on $\mathcal{F}^W_{\tau_a}$ and say that $X(t-\tau_a)$ is just another Brownian motion, hence
$$
\mathbb{P}(X(t-\tau_a)<0\mid\mathcal{F}^W_{\tau_a})=\frac12
$$
and we conclude
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\chi_{\sup_{s\in[0,t]} W(s)\geq a}\mathbb{P}(X(t-\tau_a)<0\mid\mathcal{F}^W_{\tau_a})\right]=
\mathbb{E}\left[\chi_{\sup_{s\in[0,t]} W(s)\geq a}\cdot\frac12\right]
=\frac12\mathbb{P}\left(\sup_{s\in[0,t]} W(s)\geq a\right).
$$